# Why you would choose ASP.NET MVC over SPA + ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm asking this just to see experiences from others. 
For most of the cases having ASP MVC web site is an overhead. At least for me it's much cleaner and easier to have WebAPI which responds with JSON and then you can attach either SPA application or Mobile app or whatever.

I have a feeling that if you are using ASP MVC controllers will not be controllers, but controllers full of the if conditions and some session bags which are hanging around. Views are combination of HTML and Razor which in most cases looks really ugly and full of "TODOs" ;)

I can understand if it's used in older projects and now we just need to  maintain them. But when you are starting a new one, why you would choose ASP.NET MVC or any other similar framework?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is all about your expectations - if you need REST you should take WebAPI of course, but in case of RPC Style Actions requirements in your project, MVC will be better choice

Comment: OK, if I need REST I can't choose ASP MVC so that's clear. But I asked this question to see if there is any logical reason why someone will choose MVC. What is so special that someone will say: "OK, MVC is way to go". I personally don't like MVC so I want to see what other people are saying.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the resources available. If you have a team already that is doing all pure UI (all request/response to the backend is via a RESTful API), then you can have those team create the UI for you and you can focus on the API. These UI applications are mostly client-facing products.

But sometimes in your team there is a need to develop in-house or internal applications such admin/operations applications, and the UI requirement is not as sophisticated , the teams skillset is not heavy on UI, and there is a need to develop the application ASAP, then I would go with MVC.